# Image containing errors after upload in php

Tags: php, image, api, rest

I am working on Reactjs and Php and sending image data using multiplart form data and trying to upload image using base64 ,

1. Image is uploading to server but whenever i try to open that image then getting
   message "it apperar that we dont support this file format"
2. Every image is uploding "jpg" format i want image should be same as user upload (dynamic extension instead of static)

I tried with following code, Where i am wrong ?

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
$files=file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
$image2 = base64_decode($files);
image = base64_decode(explode( ',', $files)[1]);
$image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$path = base_url().'admin_panel/assets/images/';
  
file_put_contents(
  "uploads/".$image_name.".jpg",
  base64_decode(
    str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $image)
  )
);
```

And i am getting following array after ...( Print_R($_FILES));

```
 [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => news.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpAC8FrQ
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 736493
        )
```

Comment: `image = base64_decode(explode( ',', $files)[1]);`...did you miss a `$` from the start of this line?

Comment: `dynamic extension instead of static`...so what's stopping you from getting the extension from the original filename provided in `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`. It's trivial to google how to get the extension from a filename using PHP.

Comment: Also, you are using base64_decode 3 times...why? Once should be plenty. (Although `$image2` appears to be an un-used, redundant variable so it's unclear why that line even exists). And also, I see no reason why the data in $_FILES would be base64-encoded to begin with.

Comment: Also, you seem to be expecting the data to be sent via JSON, and are trying to decode the entire input stream as if it's a JSON string, and yet simultaneously expecting the images to be send via multipart upload and ending up in $_FILES. That is unlikely to work...either the whole input is JSON, or it's not. How exactly is the client sending the request to your PHP script? What debugging have you done? There isn't a great deal of your script which really makes any sense.

Comment: @ADyson i am using multipart form data in Reactjs kindly tell me how can i image upload then ?

Comment: Well I've given you some hints already, please read them carefully. Again: Firstly you seem to have a typo as I mentiond...fix that first. Secondly, try removing all the base64_decode stuff and just save the file using move_uploaded_file - have you actually debugged to see if the file data is being received by PHP in base64 format?? Or just assumed? Thirdly, if you're using a multi-part upload then you can't json_decode the rest of the uploaded data, it won't be JSON. The rest should be in $_POST, as per normal procedure (unless you've done something really weird in your upload code).

Comment: Also, start with the basics: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php - try to upload from a standard HTML form and get your server-side code working. Then, if you've written anything extra in your react app instead of the direct upload from a form, then you can try to integrate that. One step at a time, please.

Comment: It might also help explain this code if you show us the AJAX code that is sending this data to the server

Comment: @RiggsFolly I not using ajax i am using this with Reactjs , means i am using multipart form data using axios (api) and trying to upload image into server

Comment: @ADyson updated my question , kindly check

Comment: Axios sends an ajax request, so if that's what you're doing then yes it's using ajax

Comment: But anyway, the print_r doesn't tell us much, but there's still nothing to make anyone think the data would be in base64 when it's uploaded. Do you specifically encode it before uploading? Try saving the file normally as I described.

Comment: @ADyson can you properly write formatted code please so i can check and implemnt at my side

Comment: Please review the link I already provided...that's why I posted it.

Comment: And like I said...get it working with a simple HTML form, and then try to plug in the axios stuff.